# Converting Perspective Transformed Image Coordinates to Source Image Coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm working on line detections. I implement perspective transform to source image and determine line coordinates on transformed image but what i want do is transform this coordinates to my source image. All ideas are welcome.

Source image
[image]

Detected Image
[image]

Also my transform code is here.

```
def PerspectiveTransform(img):
global inversematrix
# Frame e perspective transform uygulanması.
IMAGE_H = img.shape[0]
IMAGE_W = img.shape[1]
src = np.float32([[170, IMAGE_H], [450, 505], [850, 520], [1040, IMAGE_H]])
dst = np.float32([[400, IMAGE_H], [400, 0], [950, 0],[950, IMAGE_H]])
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst) # The transformation matrix
Minv = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(dst, src) # Inverse transformation
inversematrix = Minv
warped_img = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (IMAGE_W, IMAGE_H)) # Image warping
return cv2.cvtColor(warped_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: Invert the perspective warp matrix and project the points back from the perspective to the original

Comment: I've already been trying what you say but I don't know how to do. @fmw42